# After increasing max_allowed_packet in mysql, every time I load the long text data from db, it destroy the session so that I would be sign out?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, session-variables

I increased the `max_allowed_packet` so I could save long text inside my database.

I did it by adding this line in my `/etc/my.cnf`: (default is 1M)

```
max_allowed_packet=5M
```

However, when I load the page which query the saved data. It destroyed my session so I would be signed out automatically!

When I delete the long text record from database. Everything is fine!

I guess there should be some kind of threshold for the query or something like this that need to be increased beside the `max_allowed_packet`. What did I miss!?

BTW, I use mysql on EC2 AWS.

UPDATE: I see in [this thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45665/what-max-allowed-packet-is-big-enough-and-why-do-i-need-to-change-it?noredirect=1&lq=1) they talk about changing two other variables:

```
net_buffer_length
```

And `max_allowed_packet` in client! Where can I change this one. Does it mean it depends on the configuration of clients !!

Do you think these two parameters are the problems?

Comment: If you're going to increase it, increase it for real. `512M` minimum.

Comment: @tadman ok, this is for test, I wanted to get to the threshold, then I will see what is the reasonable max for my application. Even with more than 1M I will be signed off. It destroy my session! I missed something!

Comment: Crank it up a lot to rule this out as a factor.

Comment: If max_allowed_packet on the server doesn't match the setting on the client then **#boom** when the side configured with the larger setting sends data exceeding the smaller setting.

Comment: Possibly the `[client]` section of my.cnf is what you're looking for?